# Product setDescription not working with HTML

Tags: magento2, product, magento-2.1, product-attribute

If I run $product->setDescription($text) with plain text and then save the object, it works as expected.

However, if $text contains HTML, it does not update the record.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use like Magento natively uses like this:

```
$product->setDescription('Description with <b>html tag</b>');
```

> Check the method like you get the description too.

Comment: Okay, that does work, so Magento must not like the markup in the description. I'm migrating over 3,000 products, I hope there's an easy solution to this!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the HTML format product description. You need to follow this step.

Go to Magento admin panel -> Catalog -> Attribute -> Manage Attribute

Search "**description**" attribute_code , click on it.

find the option "Enable WYSIWYG" set it to "Yes" then save.

Now try to set $product->setDescription($text) it will save HTML Data.

Comment: WYSIWYG is indeed enabled, and I can save simple markup. But when I try to import data from an old site, it fails. There must be something in the string that it doesn't like.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not with the source code but with the CSV file format. While saving the CSV file, you have to choose the character set as UTF-8. Then it should be working. I tried and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

When I added `<![CDATA[...]]>` to description, magento save this with HTML tags. I use *Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product* to fast save product.

```
$productResource = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product');
$product->setDescription($string_variable_with_meta_cdata);
$productResource->saveAttribute($product, 'description');
```